# How to install latest stable Exim+rspamd version?

Tags: debian, spam-prevention, gentoo, exim

This should have to be a corporate mail-spam filter box.
We have been looking for various spam filtering options and would like to try rspamd, but there is a catch - rspamd is in active development and is not included in many distributions. I wanted to try it with exim. Exim homepage states that all versions before current is obsolete.

Our corporate "standard" is OpenSuse. I could manage to convince to use Debian for some special purposes, like this, because Debian/Ubuntu has come clear advantages but Debian packages for exim/rspamd are outdated. I have no choice but to do source install.

So here is my dilemma, what would be the best course of action that is not a hardcode hackers way - install Gentoo and spend a week compiling everything from source and repeat every time when You have to update Your install (not very cost-effective solution for a corporate use) Or make a mixed install - Install some parts of Debian then make source compiles or even hack Your own deb package? (Haven't done that yet)

Additional challenge for me is that I am not very familiar with rspamd and I haven't managed exim for ages, therefore I would love a distro or solution that would provide me with some handy tools to put all things together with as little pain and frustration as possible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of `rspamd (0.6.10)` available on the official debian repo is outdated :

> [Debian official repos](https://rspamd.com/downloads.html#system2)
>
> Rspamd is also available in some versions of Debian and Ubuntu. However, we are looking for an active maintainer for rspamd in these ‘official’ repos, as now rspamd is terribly outdated there.
>
> Please DO NOT use those packages, as they are no longer supported.

You can install the newest stable version of `rspamd` as recommanded on rspamd website :

```
apt-get install -y lsb-release wget # optional
CODENAME=`lsb_release -c -s`
wget -O- https://rspamd.com/apt/gpg.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://rspamd.com/apt/ $CODENAME main" > /etc/apt sources.list.d/rspamd.list
echo "deb-src http://rspamd.com/apt/ $CODENAME main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rspamd.list
apt-get update
apt-get --no-install-recommends install rspamd
```

---

The available version of Exim on debian stable is `4.84.2-2` , you can easily upgrade the version to `4.87-3` by installing the needed package from backports through the following steps, run:

```
apt edit-sources
```

add the following line to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Update and install `exim4`

```
apt-get update
apt-get remove exim4
apt-get -t jessie-backports install exim4
```

You can install the `4.88` version of `exim` from testing using [`apt-pinning`](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) way but **it is not recommanded** because you can break some dependencies .